# How to use filter function in multiple states at one time in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter

I want to filter the data from my multiple states at one time. But I am getting the data of only second state. 
I have two states and both states are getting seprate data from seprate apis. Now I want to filter the data from it. thank youI don't know what i m doing wrong so pls help me and look at my code.

```
searchFeatured = value => {
  const filterFeatured = (
    this.state.latestuploads || this.state.featuredspeakers
  ).filter(item => {
    let featureLowercase = (item.name + " " + item.title).toLowerCase();
    let searchTermLowercase = value.toLowerCase();
    return featureLowercase.indexOf(searchTermLowercase) > -1;
  });
  this.setState({
    featuredspeakers: filterFeatured,
    latestuploads: filterFeatured
  });
};


    class SearchPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      featuredspeakers: [],
      latestuploads: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .all([
        axios.get(
          'https://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/featured/speakers',
        ),
        axios.get(
          'https://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/featured/latest-uploads',
        ),
      ])
      .then(responseArr => {
        //this will be executed only when all requests are complete

        this.setState({
          featuredspeakers: responseArr[0].data,
          latestuploads: responseArr[1].data,

          loading: !this.state.loading,
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused why you're using the || operator. Do you not want to merge the arrays and then do a filter?.. I.E `[...this.state.latestuploads, ...this.state.featuredspeakers]`

Comment: oh sorry, i said i a don't know wht i am doing,,yes i want to do like this

Answer (score 0):

Using the || (OR) statement will take the first value if not null/false or the second. What you should do is combine the arrays

You should try something like

```
[...this.state.latestuploads, ... this.state.featuredspeakers].filter(item=>{});
```

Comment: no bro I am getting multiple data by doing this..I have two states and both states are getting seprate data from seprate apis. Now I want to filter the data from it. I don't want to merge the arrays.. Pls look at my updated code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should apply your filter on the lists separately then. Sample code below =>

```
const searchFeatured = value => {
    this.setState({
        featuredspeakers: customSearch(this.state.featuredspeakers, value),
        latestuploads: customSearch(this.state.latestuploads, value)
    });
};


const customSearch = (items, value) => {
    return items.filter(item => {
        let featureLowercase = (item.name + " " + item.title).toLowerCase();
        let searchTermLowercase = value.toLowerCase();
        return featureLowercase.indexOf(searchTermLowercase) > -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am gettiing an error of customsearch not defined. my searchFeatured function is onChangeText in <TextInput /> field but where do i exactly call this customSearch function??

Comment: You have to declare the variables, I changed my sample code, it should work.

As you can read, the customSearch function is called inside the setState... I suggested to create another function to make it clean...

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed, I couldn't get your code to work at all - `searchFeatured` is not called anywhere. But I have some thoughts, which I hope will help.

I see that you're setting `featuredspeakers` and `latestuploads` in `componentDidMount`. Those are large arrays with lots of data.

But then, in `searchFeatured`, you are completely overwriting the data that you downloaded and replacing it with search/filter results. Do you really intend to do that?

Also, as other people mentioned, your use of the `||` operator is just returning the first array, `this.state.latestuploads`, so only that array is filtered.

One suggestion that might help is to set up a very simple demo class which only does the filtering that you want. Don't use `axios` at all. Instead, set up the initial state with some mocked data - an array of just a few elements. Use that to fix the filter and search functionality the way that you want. Here's some demo code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.searchFeatured = this.searchFeatured.bind(this);
        this.customSearch = this.customSearch.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            featuredspeakers: [],
            latestuploads: [],
        };
    }

    searchFeatured = value => {
        // overwrite featuredspeakers and latestuploads! Downloaded data is lost
        this.setState({
            featuredspeakers: this.customSearch(this.state.featuredspeakers, value),
            latestuploads: this.customSearch(this.state.latestuploads, value),
        });
    };


    customSearch = (items, value) => {
        let searchTermLowercase = value.toLowerCase();
        let result = items.filter(item => {
            let featureLowercase = (item.name + " " + item.title).toLowerCase();
            return featureLowercase.indexOf(searchTermLowercase) > -1;
        });
        return result;
    }


    handlePress(obj) {
        let name = obj.name;
        this.searchFeatured(name);
    }

    handleReset() {
        this.setState({
            featuredspeakers: [{ name: 'Buffy', title: 'Slayer' }, { name: 'Spike', title: 'Vampire' }, { name: 'Angel', title: 'Vampire' }],
            latestuploads: [{ name: 'Sarah Michelle Gellar', 'title': 'Actress' }, { name: 'David Boreanaz', title: 'Actor' }],
            loading: !this.state.loading,
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleReset();
    }

    getList(arr) {
        let output = [];
        if (arr) {
            arr.forEach((el, i) => {
                output.push(<Text>{el.name}</Text>);
            });
        }
        return output;
    }

    render() {
        let slayerList = this.getList(this.state.featuredspeakers);
        let actorList = this.getList(this.state.latestuploads);
        return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Search results for Slayer"
            onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this, {name: 'Slayer'})}></Button>
            <Button title="Search results for Actor"
            onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this, {name: 'Actor'})}></Button>
            <Button title="Reset"
            onPress={this.handleReset.bind(this)}></Button>
            <Text>Found Slayers?</Text>
            {slayerList}
            <Text>Found Actors?</Text>
            {actorList}
        </View>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your response. The searchFeatured is called on<TextInput
                onChangeText={value => this.searchFeatured(value) />

Comment: You should change your searchFeatured method to print out what is in the component state, so you can see what's going on. I added a TextInput in my example, and as I type, most of the featuredspeakers and latestuploads data gets eliminated. This is because your code reassigns these values. I think you probably don't want to do this.

Comment: So just put this code at the top of your `searchFeatured` method: `console.log("searchFeatured: value " + value + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));`. Then watch the output in Metro server while you type into your `TextInput`. Hopefully that gives some clarity about what is happening.